# How does one formally define ordering of $n$ points in a circle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

Suppose $n$ is a positive integer greater than or equal to $4$. How does one formally define the statement, "Points $A_1,...,A_n$ are arranged in a circle in that order"? Note, I do not require that they be either clockwise or counterclockwise, in fact, clockwise and counterclockwise does not make sense in my question, because there is no coordinate system. I am merely requiring that they are in that order. I know it when I see it, but I am interested in how to define it mathematically in Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Hints: "in a circle" is fairly easy (it says that the $A_i$ are all equidistant from some other point $C$. The ordering property can then be expressed using scalar product to express the angular relationships $A_iCA_j$.

Comment: @user107952  Given a regular pentagon $A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5$, is it reasonable to consider that $A_1$, $A_3$, $A_5$, $A_2$, $A_4$ are also points on a circle in that order?

Comment: @Apass.Jack No. I do not allow skipping over points in my definition.

Comment: @user107952 Fair enough. I would like to note that any three distinct points $x,y,z$ on a circle in that order defines an orientation of the circle.  We *can* define formally in Euclidean geometry whether $x,y,z$ and $y,z,w$ are consistent in order or not.  This kind of consistency + no skipping points will be another characterization of your definition/situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to think about things that is completely coordinate-free *and* doesn't involve comparing lengths/angles/etc.:

Suppose I have a circle $C$ and *distinct* points $X,Y\in C$. We get two corresponding arcs in $C$ with endpoints $X$ and $Y$. (Explicitly, consider the equivalence relation $\approx$ on $C\setminus \{X,Y\}$ given by $U\approx V$ iff $\overline{UV}\cap \overline{XY}=\emptyset$.) Now given a sequence of points $\mathscr{A}=\langle A_1,...,A_n\rangle$ on a circle $C$, the sequence $\mathscr{A}$ is **in order** iff for each $1\le i<n$ one of the two arcs formed in $C$ by $A_i$ and $A_{i+1}$ contains no other point from $\mathscr{A}$.

Strictly speaking, (first-order) Euclidean geometry can't directly talk about finite sequences. So instead, the above paragraph should be thought of as a strategy for making sense of in-ordered-ness of length-$n$ sequenes for each fixed $n$.