# How to formally define in Euclidean geometry whether two triples of noncollinear points are in the same orientation?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, definition

Assume we are working in the Euclidean plane. We are given six points $P, Q, R, P', Q', R'$ such that $P, Q, R$ are noncollinear and $P', Q', R'$ are also noncollinear. How does one formally define the relation "The triples $(P,Q,R)$ and $(P',Q',R')$ have the same orientation". In other words, they are both clockwise or both counterclockwise. Of course, in a general Euclidean plane, clockwise and counterclockwise don't have an absolute meaning. One can only say that two triples of noncollinear points have the same orientation. It is that definition that I am searching for.

Comment: Via translation and scaling, we can assume WLOG that all six points lie on the same circle.  Then use the "arcs" strategy [from my answer your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687281/how-does-one-formally-define-ordering-of-n-points-in-a-circle/4687307#4687307).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one natural way to define it.  There is a unique translation $t$ that sends $P$ to $P'$, and then a unique rotation $r$ around $P'$ that sends $t(Q)$ to a point on the ray from $P'$ to $Q'$.  Then $(P,Q,R)$ and $(P',Q',R')$ have the same orientation iff $r(t(R))$ is on the same side of line $P'Q'$ as $R$ is.

(The intuition here is that translations and rotations preserve orientation, so you can assume $P=P'$ and $Q$ and $Q'$ are on the same ray from $P$, and then having the orientation is just determined by which side of line $PQ$ the third point is on.)